# flex event triggered on component re-render?

Tags: apache-flex

What's the call analogous to `creationComplete` that happens every time a component is rendered?  I want to rerun a function every time the component gets rendered (it has to make an HTTP request, but the url it calls changes each time) and I can't figure out how to do it.

For context:

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%"
     creationComplete="loadGallery()">

private function loadGallery():void {
            var src:String = "http://localhost:3000/car_type/" + UserPreference.getInstance().carType.toString() + ".xml";
            Alert.show(src);
            httpService.url = src;
            httpService.send();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creationComplete use [updateComplete](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event%3aupdateComplete).

Answer (score 1):

I would override the updateDisplayList method for the component and add a call to your loadGallery method there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I bet this would work for many situations; but it depends what he wants his function to do.  I wouldn't want to wrap httpService calls into an updateDisplayList() method, since they have nothing to do w/ updating the display of the component.  It is also possible a component may go through a render event w/o running updateDisplayList.  For example, if size and properties were invalidated, but displayList was not.  Listening to the updateComplete method is the approach I would take (as per my answer).

Comment: @Flextras: I like your answer better :)

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event:render maybe?

Comment: Based on Docs, it sounds like the renderer event is dispatched before the component is renderered, whereas the original poster wants to run code after it was renderered.  I'm unclear if this would work for the original poster.  In the context of Flex, I believe updateComplete is what he is looking for.